# Allow HTML entities in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, html-entities

I just tried to write a comment with an em dash—unsuccessfully, I might add—by using the `&mdash;` HTML entity.

Maybe I'm spoiled by the Markdown support for questions and answers, and I do understand the reasons behind limiting the fanciness allowed in comments, but it would be fantastic if SE sites could detect the use of an HTML entity in the comments and avoid escaping the initial ampersand.

Of course, the obvious workarounds are to 1) copy the character in its non-entity form into the comment text area or 2) break open the inspector and add the character in its entity form directly to the contents of the `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: Workaround 3: Just type the actual character, since the site supports Unicode.

Comment: For those characters that exist on a keyboard, or have a keyboard combination/code on the operating system you're using, yes.